# Using wildcard at the beginning of grep expression affects the output

Tags: grep, regular-expression, wildcards

I observer the following behavior of `grep` when runinng it five times:

```
me@asus:~/go/src/company/topology-front$ lsof |grep 'READ'
vim        4788                  me    4u      REG                8,2     12288   32247694 /home/me/go/src/company/topology-front/.README.md.swp
me@asus:~/go/src/company/topology-front$ lsof |grep 'README.md*'
vim        4788                  me    4u      REG                8,2     12288   32247694 /home/me/go/src/company/topology-front/.README.md.swp
me@asus:~/go/src/company/topology-front$ lsof |grep 'README.md'
vim        4788                  me    4u      REG                8,2     12288   32247694 /home/me/go/src/company/topology-front/.README.md.swp
me@asus:~/go/src/company/topology-front$ lsof |grep '*README.md*'
me@asus:~/go/src/company/topology-front$ lsof |grep '*README.md'
me@asus:~/go/src/company/topology-front$
```

I couldn't understand why the last two tries of `grep` are not returning any result.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`grep` patterns are regular expressions (aka regex, regexp, RE), *basic* regular expressions (BRE) unless one of `-E`/`-F`/`-P`/`-K`/`-X` option (only the first two of which being standard) is used.

`*` is a regexp operator that matches 0 or more of the preceding *atom*. For instance, `d*` matches 0 or more `d`s. In BREs, when at the start of the pattern or when following the `^` or `\(` regexp operators, it matches a literal `*` only (it's also taken literally inside `[...]` bracket expressions).

So `grep '*README.md*'` matches on lines that contain a literal `*` followed by `README` followed by any single character (the `.` regexp operator) followed by `m` followed by any number of `d`s. Since *any number* includes 0, that's functionally equivalent to `grep '*README.m'` (which would make no difference to which lines are being matched, only on what may be matched within the line (which would show with the `--color` option of GNU `grep`  for instance)).

For instance, it would match on those 2 lines:

```
*README mike
^^^^^^^^^
DONT***README-mddd
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(the `^`s showing what within the line is matched by the regular expression, which you could see with `--color`)

Here, it seems you're confusing regular expressions with shell wildcard patterns. The `*` wildcard operator which matches on 0 or more characters can be written `.*` in regular expressions. But doing:

```
grep '.*README\.md.*'
```

would again be the same as:

```
grep 'README\.md'
```

As `grep` looks for a match *within* the line as opposed to finding lines that match the pattern exactly (for which you need `-x`).

With ast-open `grep`, which is also `ksh93`'s `grep` builtin (not always built-in by default, and you need to enable it by putting `/opt/ast/bin` ahead of `$PATH`), you can use the `-K` option for `grep` to use shell wildcards (extended ksh93 ones). So with that `grep` implementation, you can do:

```
grep -K 'README.md'
```

or

```
grep -xK '*README.md*'
```

to match on lines that contain `README.md`.

With that same implementation, wildcard matching can also be enabled within extended (`-E`), *augmented* (`-X`) or perl-like (`-P`) regular expressions with the `(?K)` operator (and `\(?K\)` in basic regular expressions which actually breaks POSIX conformance, so I wouldn't rely on it as it could be removed in a future version). So you  can do:

```
grep -xE '(?K)*README.md*'
```

there.

With any modern `grep` implementation, you can also do:

```
grep -F README.md
```

For a fixed-string search (where `.` above matches a literal `.` instead of any character).

Comment: FWIW: Perl complains about `*` or `+` at the start of the regex, and so does `grep -P`

Comment: @ilkkachu, so does `grep -E` with several implementations. That `*` treated literally when at the beginning is only specified for BREs. With other REs, YMMV.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I didn't find the specification for the leading asterisk. Is it documented anywhere? I'm using plain `grep` (or `grep -G`) too.

Comment: @iBug, if you reed the answer more carefully, you'll notice what (I think) you're referring to is for ast-open's `grep -K` which uses shell patterns (where `*` matches any number of characters).

Comment: @iBug, if you mean `*` not being special when the first character of a BRE, see [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks a lot. Would you mind answering my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57133853/5958455) for an extra 25 rep on SO?